# Assign tags to all resources of a nested stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, aws-cdk, nested-stack

I'm trying to make use of NestedStack but I can't find the way to propagate the tags to all the resources of the stack as the NestedStack construct does not have the field `tags` as it's the case in the construct `Stack`.

So, for example, I can't run

```js
const stack = cdk.Stack.of(scope);

for (let key in props.tags) {
    cdk.Tags.of(scope).add(key, tags[key], {
        applyToLaunchedInstances: false,
        excludeResourceTypes: ["AWS::EC2::EIP"]
    })
}
```

**Error Message**

```
Property 'tags' does not exist on type 'ekstackprops'.ts(2339)
```

Where `ekstackprops` extends `NestedStackProps`.

Answer (score 2):

If you add tags to a scope that includes a `NestedStack` construct, the CDK propagates the tags down to the nested stack's child resources at synth-time.

For instance, if `MyStack` contains a `MyNestedStack`, which in turn has a `MyNestedLambda` construct, the following will add a tag to all three:

```js
declare const MyStack: cdk.Stack // includes a MyNestedStack construct

cdk.Tags.of(MyStack).add('TagName', 'TaggyMcTagFace');
```